# wpf datagrid total row

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I want to make a total row in a wpf datagrid like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rU8ln.png) one.
I don't know how to create such a row in xaml. It should be frozen when I scroll through the other rows.

Someone said it is possible to add a total item to the data source and create a special template for that item. But this seems a bit weird.

I found no working solution for that. Has someone an idea how to do that?

Comment: You could extend the datagrid header. StackPanel and put a label or textblock for the totals in there?

Comment: @Stuart Great! Thank you. I did not thought it would be that easy and searched for the wrong questions.

Answer (score 0):

You could bind your TextBlock.Text to your value. To do this for all of your columns you could change the ContentTemplate for your DataGrid Header like this

```
<DataGrid ...>
   <DataGrid.Resources>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
         <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
               <DataTemplate>
                  <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
               </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
         </Setter>
      </Style>
   </DataGrid.Resources>
   <DataGrid.Columns>
      <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}" Header="Header Text">
   </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Alternatively, to do it for each column you could change `TextBlock.Text` in your `Header` template to use a binding

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
```

and then your column would look like this

```
<DataGridTextColumn 
    Binding="{Binding Name}" 
    HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource ColumnHeaderTemplate}"
    Header="Header Text"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, to solve it I created a dock panel and docked the Data Grid to the top. I then created a horizontal stack panel with a text box for each table column and populated them with the required totals, this was then docked at the bottom of the dock panel. With the Data grids ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility set to auto, the totals rows is always visible at the bottom of the data grid and if the data grid gets to large for its container it is wrapped in a scrolling container (with the totals row still visible).